# Instrumentation Error even if already Instrumented. (Standalone Instrumentation, using CaptainCasa Framework)

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

Even if Eclipse already said that class is instrumented, when I click "Reload Server" on CaptainCasa toolset, error occurs

`org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException: you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models. It is expected that you have a file activejdbc_models.properties on classpath`...

[Here is the Instrumentation message from Eclipse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzGY5.png)

[Here is the error to make it more detailed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6WQz.png)

Answer (score 0):

the only reason for you to see this error is when your models are not instrumented. It is possible that your framework or an IDE wipes instrumented models and replaces them with non-instrumented.The message  is self-explanatory.